# MYSQL select doesn't work on previous versions

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following `select` that finds the max,min,average temperatures and the datetime that occurred on specific range of date. It works perfect on 10.3.22-MariaDB but on 10.0.38-MariaDB it return errors. It looks like it doesn't support windows functions. Is it possible to help me that this `select` will work on 10.0.38?

Thank you in advance

```
SELECT DISTINCT max(Temperature) OVER () as maxtemp,        
                min(Temperature) OVER () as mintemp, 
                avg(Temperature) OVER () as avtemp, 
                FIRST_VALUE(DateTimeValue) OVER (ORDER BY Temperature ASC) as dt_at_min,             
                FIRST_VALUE(DateTimeValue) OVER (ORDER BY Temperature DESC) as dt_at_max 
FROM TempHistory 
        WHERE date(DateTimeValue) = '2020-07-08'AND 
        SensorPosition = 'Base' and 
        Location = 'Home'
```

The table

```
Temperature    DateTimeValue         WarnCrit     Location    SensorPosition
29.1        2020-06-22 10:08:30         0          Home           Base
29.2        2020-06-22 09:38:28         0          Home           Base
29.2        2020-06-22 09:08:26         0          Home           Base
28.9        2020-06-22 08:38:26         0          Home 2         1stFloor
28.7        2020-06-22 08:08:24         0          Home           Base
28.7        2020-06-22 07:38:22         0          Home 2         1stFloor
29.2        2020-06-22 07:08:21         0          Home           Base
29.8        2020-06-22 06:38:20         0          Store          Entrance
29.9        2020-06-22 06:08:18         0          Store          Entrance
```

The error (i didn't include all of them, but if need it, i will)

```
Error
Static analysis:

42 errors were found during analysis.

An alias was previously found. (near "maxtemp" at position 44)
An alias was expected. (near " " at position 43)
Unexpected token. (near "maxtemp" at position 44)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 51)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "min" at position 78)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 81)
Unexpected token. (near "Temperature" at position 82)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 93)
Unexpected token. (near "OVER" at position 95)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 100)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 101)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "as" at position 103)
Unexpected token. (near "mintemp" at position 106)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 113)
```

Result on MariaDB 10.3.22

```
maxtemp    mintemp    avtemp    dt_at_min              dt_at_max
30          28.6      29.668    2020-07-08 07:00:18    2020-07-08 9:00:23
```

Comment: You must rewrite your query fully. Use subqueries with aggregate functions.

Comment: Thank you for answering! do you have the kind to give me an example?

Comment: It's puzzling that your working query returns data not present in the table

Comment: The data are not present because i dint include all of them, just a sample of the first rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB didn't start supporting window functions until version 10.2, so you need to rewrite the query using a subquery to get the min/max/avg temperatures and then joining that to the original table twice to get the min/max date values. Note I've only included data from what you have provided in the question, but you should be able to expand it to your complete table:

```
SELECT MIN(mintemp) AS mintemp,
       MAX(maxtemp) AS maxtemp,
       AVG(avtemp) AS avtemp,
       MIN(t1.DateTimeValue) AS dt_at_min,
       MAX(t2.DateTimeValue) AS dt_at_max
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(Temperature) AS mintemp,
         MAX(Temperature) AS maxtemp,
         AVG(Temperature) AS avtemp
  FROM TempHistory
  WHERE DATE(DateTimeValue) = '2020-06-22' AND 
        SensorPosition = 'Base' AND 
        Location = 'Home'
) agg
JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM TempHistory
  WHERE DATE(DateTimeValue) = '2020-06-22' AND 
        SensorPosition = 'Base' AND 
        Location = 'Home'
) t1 ON t1.Temperature = agg.mintemp
JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM TempHistory
  WHERE DATE(DateTimeValue) = '2020-06-22' AND 
        SensorPosition = 'Base' AND 
        Location = 'Home'
) t2 ON t2.Temperature = agg.maxtemp
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
mintemp     maxtemp     avtemp      dt_at_min               dt_at_max
28.7        29.2        29.08000    2020-06-22 08:08:24     2020-06-22 09:38:28
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=b5681060fad68e1dc2638cbae794cc12)

Comment: Thank you for answering! Do you have the kind to add the where too? also i will edit the table for better view

Comment: After i add the WHERE date(DateTimeValue) = '2020-07-08' I got the following error  #1052 - Column 'DateTimeValue' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: @GKal See my edit, I've included the `WHERE` clause and your updated data. Note the `WHERE` clause has to be in all three subqueries

Comment: Maybe i am wrong, but the max temp its 29.9   2020-06-22 06:08:18

Comment: @GKal I had a copy/paste typo in the query; I've updated it and the demo. The demo also includes your original query so you can see it gets the same result. Note that maximum temperature is not when `Location = 'Home'` which is why you're not seeing it.

Comment: i am so sorry i see now my mistake!! on where you have the home and base, i am so sorry

Comment: @GKal no worries - check the query with some other data, I think you should find it works...

Comment: When i run the select it returns NULL and olny when i delete the location and sensorposition i got data that return values with many decimals e.g. 26.100000381469727 Any ideas why?

Comment: @GKal it's a floating point precision issue. You can work around it by using `ROUND` to round to 1 or 2 decimal points e.g. `ROUND(AVG(avtemp), 2)`.

Comment: i got that Thanks! But i dont understand why so many decimals, since i add only 1 digit, its not crucial for sure! Also any idea why i got null when i have location and sensorposition?

Comment: @GKal As I said, it's a floating point precision issue. Without seeing your actual data I don't know why you are not getting a result; I can only show the query working with the data you supplied in the question.